# Reattach baseboard tile: what glue and clamp is used?

Tags: bathroom, tile

I don't have anything that can keep these pressed into place while glue sets

How to solve?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Heavy objects can probably be placed close and use pieces of wood to wedge the tiles in place.  Pressure should not need to be that much, maybe a couple 5 gallon buckets full of water, heavy chairs.

Comment: Have you tried mastic?